# jQuery to select previous this?

Tags: jquery

jsfiddle to debug :
http://jsfiddle.net/ZpsCX/

**Newer Update:**
this is the html

```
<li>Something</li>
<div class='a'>
 <div class='x'>REMOVE</div>
</div>
```

im trying to remove LI by going to parent then previous :

```
 $('.x').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().prev().remove();
 });
```

but if i used this

```
 $('.x').click(function(){
   if(bla bla bla){ // and it returns TRUE
     $(this).parent().prev().remove();
   }
 });
```

it doesnt work

Comment: Are you looking to remove the class from the element or the element itself?

Comment: the element itself but its not the thing, i mean like any function to apply on the clicked class inside an IF condition

Comment: My apologies, I'm still not quite sure what you're asking. Can you give me a little more detail or try and flesh (code) out a little more so I can have a better idea of what you're going for?

Comment: _"it doesnt seem that .prev() works"_ - the code you've shown doesn't include any use of `.prev()`. `$(this).remove();` should remove the element that was clicked, because inside the click handler `this` is that element. What do you mean by "on a previous this"?

Comment: @nnnnnn please read the update, all i meant is IF condition blocks me of targeting the clicked element

Comment: You're code should be fine then. `this` should be the same both inside and outside of your if statement, but of course the element will only be removed when your `if` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: It only 'blocks' you if the evaluated expression returns `false`. You need to check your `if` condition. What evaluation are you testing?

Comment: The others are right, your code will work if your `if` evaluates as true, so if that isn't working please show your _actual_ code rather than "blah blah blah". Or are you saying that you want the element removed regardless of the result of the `if`?

Comment: Can you post your HTML or better yet, a jsFiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: updated again with the actualy html, thanks

Comment: How do you know that your `if` condition is true when the code runs? Try `if(true) {` and see what happens, and/or put an `alert()` or `console.log()`  inside the if block to confirm that the condition is true. Please show the actual condition instead of "bla bla bla". Note that your html isn't valid because a li should not have a div as a sibling (you could put the div _inside_ the li).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now that you've *finally* shown the full code in your fiddle, I can tell you that the problem is that you're removing the element that `this` refers to before you then try to do `$(this).parent().prev().remove();`, and that doesn't work because `this` doesn't have a parent once it's gone...

You need to do it the other way around as follows:

```
$(".x").live("click", function(x) {
    // if clicked ".x" has no siblings it must be the last one
    // in the current group
    if ($(this).siblings(".x").length == 0) {
        $(this).parent().prev().remove();
    }
    $(this).remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZpsCX/12/

Note that li elements should belong to a ul or ol, and it isn't valid to have a div as a sibling of an li (even though most browsers are forgiving about this and let you get away with it).

Comment: You're welcome. (And sorry, but I can't help pointing out that once you finally showed your actual code it only took a moment to spot the problem and come up with a solution - think how much time you could've saved if you'd just put that in your question in the first place...)

Comment: uhm, this didnt do the actual thing if there were multiple il's http://jsfiddle.net/ZpsCX/9/

Comment: Well if you're going to keep moving the goal posts what do you expect? I'll update my answer one last time...

Comment: yah sorry, been thinking all day,i guess i lost my connection to mind. u know, coding big stuff, thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/ZpsCX/11/

I removed the if statement because it always returns true. You also needed to include jQuery and add a wrapper :)

Answer (score 0):

I modified your fiddle slightly. You need to make sure jQuery is being included for one, and then also wrap your code in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.x').click(function(){
  if(true){ // and it returns TRUE
   $(this).parent().prev().remove();
  }
 });
});
```

​
Your original code will work with this.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZpsCX/4/

Comment: same result, read the code again, what i wanna do is remove something but it doesnt remove it while the IF is responding true !

Comment: you didnt get me at all ! i want to remove the il content if .x classes count is 0, please read the question again, it has nothing to do with document ready

Comment: Yep, he's got it. I got lost in the confusion. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work is because the div with `class = 'x'` is not nested inside of the li tag, so a call to .parent will never find the li.

You could nest the divs inside of the li and use this code:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Something
        <div class='a'>
            <div class='x'>REMOVE</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        Something Else
        <div class='a'>
            <div class='x'>REMOVE</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.x').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('li').remove();
 });​
```

[JSFIDDLE Example](http://jsfiddle.net/flynfish/QK64e/)